# Package creation and __init__.py content

Tags: python, python-import

This question seems to be pretty obvious, but I cannot find any satisfactory answer...

So, I have a package named `notes` in a location known by `PYTHONPATH`, where I would like the main module to be called per the package:

```
my_python_scripts/
 +-- notes/
      +-- __init__.py
      +-- notes.py        <-- this is the main module, containing a main() function
      +-- main_window.py
      +-- main_window.ui
```

The aim behind is to use it this way:

```
import notes
notes.main()
```

but in this case, I only get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\notes_launcher.py", line 13, in <module>
    notes.main()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'
```

Currently, I know how to make it work differently:

- either by calling the full hierarchy, which is a bit annoying and seems a bet weird to me (as the well-known `from datetime import datetime`):

  ```
  from notes import notes
  notes.main()
  ```
- or by tweaking content of the `__init__.py` (but everyone seems to agree on leaving this file empty):

  ```
  from notes import main
  ```

So, how could I do that? Should I even be dreaming of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can even do `from notes.notes import *` in __init__.py, or simply place the contents of notes.py into __init__.py and do without notes.py. People do both and there's no really pressing reason not to, as far as I know.

Comment: That's a good way to make the package appear/behave like a module, which is maybe what I unconciously desire. Btw, I'm not sure the double `notes` is necessary, as the module is local from the `__init__.py`, am I right?

Comment: In Python 3 (or Python 2.7 with `from __future__ import absolute_import`) you can't use relative imports like that. It can lead to trouble because it's possible there is another module named notes in the global namespace that's imported instead. It is possible to explicitly import from the same directory as the current module directory with `from .notes import *` though.

Comment: AAaah ok, I get the use of these relative imports now; I was only (wrongly?) relying on the fact that local modules are imported before looking to sys.path.

Answer (score 2):

For me the right way is to put what necessary in the `__init__.py` file. I see nothing bad with that. It's there for that - to do what initializations you want with your package. So if you design your package to be used simply like `import notes` the `__init__.py` file seems to me like the right place for that.

Systems like OpenERP for instance use massively this technique. *Modules* in OpenERP are Python packages which import in their `__init__.py` file all the sub-modules like *report*, *wizard* etc.

Comment: A matter of personal preference, but I prefer RemcoGerlich's suggestion of `from notes import *`, since a project will have multiple `__init__.py` files. Using Sublime's Goto Anything command, for instance, I'd type `notes` to jump to the file I want to edit, rather than getting a list of multiple `__init__.py` files. It just makes it easier to distinguish.